# Helperclass for saving structs with NSCoding

Tags: swift, struct, save, nscoding

I want to write a function for saving my struct Array. I know, that using NSCoding is the right way, but only available to classes. But I found a workaround using a class including the struct itself:

```
extension EXIFData {
    class EXIFDataClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

        var exifData: EXIFData?
...
}
```

But how do I use it (call it)? E.g. defined as

```
var exif : EXIFData
```

or (next step)

```
var exifs : [EXIFData]
```

I like to use as much as possible of the actual features of Swift 3.0, because I'm just starting. I found some different solutions for older styles and versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your class EXIFData is, but I think that you are better off saving a class that contains a EXIFData object.

Say for example you need to save a bunch of different types of data including EXIFData, then you could create a class like the following which decodes, encodes, and initializes a class with an EXIFData type:

```
class UserData: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var exifData: EXIFData
    //other variables of data....

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        exifData = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "EXIFData") as! EXIFData
        //decode other values
    }

    init(exifData: EXIFData) {
        self.exifData = exifData
        //intialize other values
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(exifData, forKey: "EXIFData")
        //encode other values
    }

}
```

Then you could initialize your class like so:

```
var myUserData = UserData(...) //initialize with EXIFData
```

And then call your user "EXIFData" like so:

```
myUserData.exifData
```

Comment: EXIFData is a struct. Only this data is needed to be loaded and saved. And finally I want to save an array of it: [EXIFData]